# I don't know how to close the main window in javafxml

Tags: java, fxml, scenebuilder

I don't know how to close the main window in java fxml.

This part of code is in the class Main:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    Parent root2 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("2ndwin.fxml"));
    Scene scene  = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    Scene scene2 = new Scene(root2);
    secondaryStage.setScene(scene2);
}

public void show(){
    secondaryStage.show();
}
```

I've got this. In controller i did this:

```
Main m = new Main();
m.show();`
```

but I still don't know how I can close `primaryStage`.

Please help me or tell me how I can create a new window and close the old window. I think this what I want to do - it isn't correct but I came up with it myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do it by using an object in the stage you want to close to get the window

```
    Window currentStage = OBJECTINSCENE.getScene().getWindow();
```

(Replace 'OBJECTINSCENE' with the id of anything in your scene). This gives you a reference to the stage you have open. Then call

```
currentStage.hide();
```

To close the stage when you want to.

So your show function would be as follows

```
public void show(){
    Window currentStage = OBJECTINSCENE.getScene().getWindow();
    secondaryStage.show();
    currentStage.hide();
}
```

Comment: Hey I'm new user of stackoverflow. How can i close this question ?

Comment: @MatiiMann You don't need to close the question. Once you have accepted an answer and consider your issue solved you don't need to do anything else. Questions are only closed for specific reasons you can see here:https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions